# Can't use both Gradle and Maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build, path

I was trying out Maven , then I wanted to install Gradle , but to install both Maven and Gradle you need to change the PATH environment variable to bin folder in Maven's or Gradle's installation folder

for example :

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin
```

so if I change the PATH environment variable to Gradle's bin folder Maven wont work or if I change it to Maven's bin folder Gradle wont work , so how do I solve this problem.

Comment: "_need to change the PATH environment variable_" - ARGH **no**! Never change the `PATH` - always _append_ to it. Changing the `PATH` will create strange and unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple paths to the PATH environment. Separated by `;`

Here is an example

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Gradle\Gradle 4.5\bin;
```